# ASP.NET web api cannot get application/x-www-form-urlencoded HTTP POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to web-api. I want to receive a HTTP POST data using web-api. The content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and the request body is like:

`data={"mac":"0004ED123456","model":"SG6200NXL"}`(JSON format).

My controller is like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string formData)
{
    data.Add(formData);
}
```

But formData is always null. Only when I change the request body to:

`={"mac":"0004ED123456","model":"SG6200NXL"}`

I can find `{"mac":"0004ED123456","model":"SG6200NXL"}` was saved in my `formData` string.

So my question is how should I receive the data with format:

`data={"mac":"0004ED123456","model":"SG6200NXL"}`?

And is there a easy way that I can desalinize the JSON into C#?

Thanks for help!

UPDATE:
I tried to use model, but it still not work for me.
My model is:

```
public class Device
    {
        public string mac { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
    }
```

and my HTTP POST request is:

header:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:52154
Content-Length: 46
```

body:

```
data={"mac":"0004ED123456","model":"SG6200NX"}
```

I have to use `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as far as I know because the HTTP POST is sent by a router. My job is to receive the data.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Quoting from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1#sending_form_data_via_ajax):

> By default, Web API tries to get simple types from the request URI. The **FromBody** attribute tells Web API to read the value from the request body.
>
> Web API reads the response body at most once, so only one parameter of an action can come from the request body. If you need to get multiple values from the request body, define a complex type.
>
> Second, the client needs to send the value with the following format:
>
> **=value**
>
> Specifically, the name portion of the name/value pair must be empty for a simple type.

So, if you want to post data in the format `data=string`, you have to create complex type.

```
public class MyFormData
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

And update your controller like so:

```
public void Post(MyFormData formData)
{
    //your JSON string will be in formData.Data
}
```

Of course, other alternatives for you is to change the content type to JSON, but really depends on your requirements.

Comment: I tried this way but it still not work for me. Please see my update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: your updated `Device` model would work if you send data in `mac=string&model=string` format. But your format is `data=string`, so you have to have a single property called `data` as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: how would map the form data to my class if the name has hyphens? like data={"mac":"0004ED123456","model":"SG6200NX","device-id":"aUniqueId"}

Comment: @jplara - i think you may have to go for a custom formatter - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-formatters-in-asp-net-core-mvc-web-api/

Comment: i found another option, the custom formatter was overkill for my purposes, you can accept `FormDataCollection` and that would give you access to the posted data

Answer (score 8):

This post is old, but I stumbled on it while searching for answer. I'll post how I got mine to work, maybe someone will find it useful.

Here's the request:

```
POST /api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:62798
Accept: text/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 51ee1c5f-acbb-335b-35d9-d2b8e62abc74

UID=200&EMAIL=john%40jones.com&FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=jones&PHONE=433-394-3324&CITY=Seattle&STATE_CODE=WA&ZIP=98105
```

Here's the Model:

```
public class SampleModel{
    public string UID { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string First_Name { get; set; }

    public string Last_Name { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State_Code { get; set; }

    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the POST method that automagically(FromBody) converts urlencoded values to the model.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] SampleModel value){
```

I was able to pick out any value i.e.

```
    SearchCity(value.City);
    SearchName(value.Last_Name);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create an object of your data like:

```
public class Device
{
  public string mac {get;set;}
  public string model {get;set;}
}
```

then change your controller's action method like this and pass your object to this method from consume

```
public void Post(Device deviceData)
{
    // You can extract data like deviceData.mac, deviceData.model etc
    data.Add(deviceData);
}
```

You can use one of the popular library [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) for serialize/deserialize of json object in C#

Comment: I tried your way but it seems not work for me. I still got null value. My post request header is User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:52154, and request body is data={"mac":"0004ED123456","model":"SG6200NX"}, I can only see a null value add to my data string list.

Answer (score 3):

create a model

```
public class MyClass {
    public string mac { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
}
```

and use .net JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize

```
public void Post([FromBody]string formData){
    MyClass obj = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyClass>(formData);
    //get mac and model by obj.mac obj.model
}
```

cheers :)

Comment: Serialising the model yourself is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

For asp.net core 3.x you need to supply the correct decorators to handle the request correctly:

```
[HttpPost("MyPostHandler")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyPostHandler([FromForm] string id)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded you can't expect to receive JSON.

I'm guessing you are using a form to send the data to the Web Api controller?

First you must change the **Content-type** to **application/json** and then you must ensure you are sending JSON data in your request body. If you are sending the data via a form, you could use javascript to create a JSON-object out of your form data.

To deserialize JSON in C# i recommend Json.NET: http://json.codeplex.com/