# How can I fit the request with the web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So I'm sitting here tossing POST request from Postman to my web api. I defined RCV, SND and TXT variables x-www-form-urlencoded.

On the server side I've defined a method

```
public ActionResult Receiver(string RCV, string SND, string TXT)
```

and that does not work. However, if I create

```
public ActionResult Receiver()
```

then that works. How can I make the web api method catch x-www-form-urlencoded parameters?

Comment: What is the request's payload? (I mean the raw string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET web api cannot get application/x-www-form-urlencoded HTTP POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369361/asp-net-web-api-cannot-get-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-http-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload of non URL parameters needs to be wrapped in a single object. You can then define the `FromBody`attribute on it.

```
public class MyContent{

   public string RCV{get;set;}
   public string SND{get;set;}
   public string TXT{get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Receiver([FromBody] MyContent contentBody)
```

If you wanted URL parameters you could keep the method as is and just add them to the URL. To specify it though you can also add the `FromUri` attribute to the parameter(s)